# phpMyAdmin won't start after upgrade from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04

Tags: phpmyadmin

After updating from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04, I can't get phpMyAdmin to work on my laptop.

I can connect to my little cloud server using phpMyAdmin, but that is still running on Ubuntu 20.04

I followed the instructions here at https://tecadmin.net/how-to-install-...-ubuntu-22-04/

When I enter localhost/phpmyadmin in my browser, I see the phpMyAdmin favicon.ico icon, but no login window where I can enter user name and password.

apache2/error.log has this after I attempt to open phpMyAdmin in the browser:

> [Sun Feb 05 11:45:12.172578 2023] [core:error] [pid 8773] [client
> ::1:54076] AH00037: Symbolic link not allowed or link target not
> accessible: /usr/share/phpmyadmin/js/vendor/codemirror/lib [Sun Feb 05
> 11:45:12.174276 2023] [core:error] [pid 8772] [client ::1:54084]
> AH00037: Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible:
> /usr/share/phpmyadmin/js/vendor/codemirror/addon/hint [Sun Feb 05
> 11:45:12.176255 2023] [core:error] [pid 8821] [client ::1:54086]
> AH00037: Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible:
> /usr/share/phpmyadmin/js/vendor/codemirror/addon/lint [Sun Feb 05
> 11:45:12.178496 2023] [core:error] [pid 9646] [client ::1:54100]
> AH00037: Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible:
> /usr/share/phpmyadmin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js [Sun Feb 05
> 11:45:12.189018 2023] [core:error] [pid 9646] [client ::1:54100]
> AH00037: Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible:
> /usr/share/phpmyadmin/js/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.bundle.min.js [Sun
> Feb 05 11:45:12.190280 2023] [core:error] [pid 8821] [client
> ::1:54086] AH00037: Symbolic link not allowed or link target not
> accessible: /usr/share/phpmyadmin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery-ui.min.js
> [Sun Feb 05 11:45:12.191505 2023] [core:error] [pid 8772] [client
> ::1:54084] AH00037: Symbolic link not allowed or link target not
> accessible:
> /usr/share/phpmyadmin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.mousewheel.js [Sun Feb
> 05 11:45:12.192675 2023] [core:error] [pid 8773] [client ::1:54076]
> AH00037: Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible:
> /usr/share/phpmyadmin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js
> [Sun Feb 05 11:45:12.212309 2023] [core:error] [pid 8773] [client
> ::1:54076] AH00037: Symbolic link not allowed or link target not
> accessible: /usr/share/phpmyadmin/js/vendor/codemirror/lib [Sun Feb 05
> 11:45:12.213699 2023] [core:error] [pid 8772] [client ::1:54084]
> AH00037: Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible:
> /usr/share/phpmyadmin/js/vendor/codemirror/mode/sql/sql.js [Sun Feb 05
> 11:45:12.213753 2023] [core:error] [pid 8821] [client ::1:54086]
> AH00037: Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible:
> /usr/share/phpmyadmin/js/vendor/codemirror/addon/runmode/runmode.js
> [Sun Feb 05 11:45:12.213789 2023] [core:error] [pid 9646] [client
> ::1:54100] AH00037: Symbolic link not allowed or link target not
> accessible: /usr/share/phpmyadmin/js/vendor/codemirror/addon/hint [Sun
> Feb 05 11:45:12.216240 2023] [core:error] [pid 8839] [client
> ::1:54116] AH00037: Symbolic link not allowed or link target not
> accessible: /usr/share/phpmyadmin/js/vendor/codemirror/addon/hint [Sun
> Feb 05 11:45:12.216278 2023] [core:error] [pid 8774] [client
> ::1:54120] AH00037: Symbolic link not allowed or link target not
> accessible: /usr/share/phpmyadmin/js/vendor/codemirror/addon/lint

There is a symlink in

/usr/share/phpmyadmin/js/vendor/codemirror/

called lib which points to

../../../../javascript/codemirror/lib which is /usr/share/javascript

The owner of /usr/share/javascript is root.

**Should I change the owner of /usr/share/javascript to www-data? Or the group to www-data?**

There was no mention of /usr/share/javascript in the tutorial I followed.

Comment: Hi from the packaging team. You should apt remove phpmyadmin and apt install phpmyadmin. Also please check: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/wiki/DebianUbuntu

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice and the link. I will read up on it! Not knowing what to do, I got it working like this: there is a symlink in /etc/apache2/conf-enabled to /usr/share/javascript  The owner was root, so apache2 couldn't open it. Same with /usr/share/nodejs I changed them both like this sudo chown -Rv www-data:www-data /usr/share/nodejs I don't know if that will cause problems elswhere, but phpmyadmin works fine, and apache2 error.log has no phpadmin related errors!

Comment: See: https://salsa.debian.org/phpmyadmin-team/phpmyadmin/-/blob/debian/4%255.2.0+dfsg1-2/debian/conf/apache.conf#L6

Comment: If you use this Apache2 option it should not be needed: `Options SymLinksIfOwnerMatch`

Comment: Thanks again! And where are my manners! As a Package Maintainer you deserve a big Thank You and Well Done for all your efforts on behalf of the Community: Great Work! I for one am very grateful to you all!

Comment: That's really nice :) 5.2.1 is now in the Ubuntu jammy PPA & Debian 12 (released soon)